# Images are not shown and file name changes when uploaded to the database

Tags: php

I can't get the picture to display/show when viewing, although the files are already stored in the database (table 'menu') https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpi8N.png. Also when I upload the images all at once, their file name would change automatically. I don't know how and why this happens. I use array to upload multiple images.

```
if (isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
    --some code here--

    if (isset($_POST["id_list"])) {
        // if id list available
        foreach($_POST["id_list"] AS $id) {
            --some code here--

            /* Handle file upload */
            if ($_FILES['upload']['error'][$id] == 'UPLOAD_ERR_OK') {

                $path = "images/newmenu/";
                $path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["upload"]["name"][$id]);
                $extension = $path_parts['extension'];
                $picture = md5(uniqid()) . "." . $extension;

                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$id], $path . "/" . $picture)) {
                    $update = " UPDATE menu
                                SET   MenuPicture='$picture'
                                WHERE MenuID=$id";

                    $mysqli->query($update) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
}
```

Below is the form and yes it does include `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<input type="file" multiple name="upload[' . $id . ']"  value="' . $record["MenuPicture"] . '">
```

Comment: Do you use any particular library?

Comment: i don't think so, no @martin

Comment: How do you output the input tag?

Answer (score 0):

Filename changes because you are generating it this way

```
$picture = md5(uniqid()) . "." . $extension;
```

[uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) is based on current time and hashing it will cause the filename to change everytime

Answer (score 0):

*When I upload the images all at once, their file name would change automatically*

It was due to this:

```
$picture = md5(uniqid()) . "." . $extension;
// And later
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$id], $path . "/" . $picture)
```

Basically, you are moving your uploaded file to a new filename for your image file, which is generated using [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) and hashed with [`md5()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php), with the file extension appended at the end.

*I can't get the picture to display/show when viewing*

How are you trying to display the picture? Is it from web browser, or you go straight to the directory and open from there? What error(s) did you get, if any?

Actually, have you tried to go to the directory and see whether the file is created inside the `images/newmenu/` directory?

Also, for the target upload directory, you might want to append it with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` so that the target directory is not dependent on where your script is located, but it's always based on the root.

By the way, you might know already, but there is an entry in PHP manual page on [uploading multiple files](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Comment: I am trying to display the picture(s) from web server and yes the file is created inside `images/newmenu/` directory

Comment: Any error message displayed when you tried to open the image file created?